# SpaCy install error -- ImportError: cannot import name remove_bilu_prefix

Tags: python, nlp, conda, spacy

When installing language models for SpaCy using Conda, I keep getting the error:

> ImportError: cannot import name remove_bilu_prefix

I have installed SpaCy using the conda install line:

> conda install -c conda-forge spacy

And it appeared to install fine, but now once I go to install the language models (en_core_web_sm), I get the above remove_bilu_prefix error.

Any ideas how to solve this? Can't find anyone that has run into the same issue.

Comment: It's not clear how you're installing the models, but note that there are unofficial mirrors of them on conda. The recommended way to install models is to use `spacy download en_core_web_sm` or similar, which should get a version compatible with your spaCy version.

Comment: When using "spacy download en_core_web_sm" I would always get a timeout error from github and it wouldn't download. So that is why I had to use the huggingface download. I would get the remove_bilu_prefix error when installing spaCy using the "pip install -U spacy" command.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure what's going on then. It sounds like you have an issue with your internet connection, like a corporate proxy or something. You can also download official models directly from release pages like this: https://github.com/explosion/spacy-models/releases/tag/en_core_web_sm-3.4.1

Answer (score 1):

I think I solved my problem. I installed SpaCy using another Conda install:

> conda install -c "conda-forge/label/cf201901" spacy

Then I followed the directions to download the language models (en_core_web_sm) straight from huggingface. Go to https://huggingface.co/spacy then go to 'models', select your model and click on 'use in spaCy' and it provides a new pip install line.